# LLVM bytecode analyzer issue

Tags: llvm, bytecode, analyzer

I am wondering why there are so many mis-matches between the `llvm-bcanalyzer` help page on [LLVM_website](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-bcanalyzer.html) and the current v3.8 that I am using. I have checked them with `v3.0` and `v3.4` and none of them are consistent.

Secondly, apparently no-matter what [option] I am passing, the output is the same.

For instance, this is the available options at `v3.8`:

```
OVERVIEW: llvm-bcanalyzer file analyzer

USAGE: llvm-bcanalyzer [options] <input bitcode>

OPTIONS:

General options:

  -block-info=<string> - Use the BLOCK_INFO from the given file
  -disable-histogram   - Do not print per-code histogram
  -dump                - Dump low level bitcode trace
  -non-symbolic        - Emit numeric info in dump even if symbolic info is available
  -show-binary-blobs   - Print binary blobs using hex escapes

Generic Options:

  -help                - Display available options (-help-hidden for more)
  -help-list           - Display list of available options (-help-list-hidden for more)
  -version             - Display the version of this program
```

Look, literally nothing is there with respect to v3.4:

```
llvm-bcanalyzer-3.0  llvm-bcanalyzer-3.4
ashouri@gbomb:~$ llvm-bcanalyzer-3.4 --help
OVERVIEW: llvm-bcanalyzer file analyzer

USAGE: llvm-bcanalyzer-3.4 [options] <input bitcode>

OPTIONS:
  -asm-verbose                            - Add comments to directives.
  -bounds-checking-single-trap            - Use one trap block per function
  -cppfname=<function name>               - Specify the name of the generated function
  -cppfor=<string>                        - Specify the name of the thing to generate
  -cppgen                                 - Choose what kind of output to generate
    =program                              -   Generate a complete program
    =module                               -   Generate a module definition
    =contents                             -   Generate contents of a module
    =function                             -   Generate a function definition
    =functions                            -   Generate all function definitions
    =inline                               -   Generate an inline function
    =variable                             -   Generate a variable definition
    =type                                 -   Generate a type definition
  -disable-debug-info-verifier            -
  -disable-histogram                      - Do not print per-code histogram
  -disable-spill-fusing                   - Disable fusing of spill code into instructions
  -dump                                   - Dump low level bitcode trace
  -enable-correct-eh-support              - Make the -lowerinvoke pass insert expensive, but correct, EH code
  -enable-load-pre                        -
  -enable-objc-arc-opts                   - enable/disable all ARC Optimizations
  -enable-tbaa                            -
  -fatal-assembler-warnings               - Consider warnings as error
  -fdata-sections                         - Emit data into separate sections
...
```

and these two are different than what is there at the website!

I would like to get the output that's written on the [llvm-bcanalyzer](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-bcanalyzer.html). Can anyone help me? Those information could be valuable for me.